# Error related to Access Control Allow Origin when trying to attach/upload a file in an ADFS environment

Tags: c#, adfs3.0

My web application uses ADFS 3.0 authentication. I have an aspx page that can be accessed by the user without having to sign in to the application. To make this page accessible I had to add code in the web.config:

```
<location path="QuickEntry.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

On this page there is a button which opens up a popup form from where the user can select file(s) to attach. Now when a file is selected it does not get attached and we see an error in the Console.

[image]

Is there any solution for this error?

Thank you.